# How packet gets routed towards IGW of my VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, nat, gateway, vpc

Below is the public route table, that is associated with IGW of my VPC,

### [image]

where first entry indicates that any packet with destination IP address(private) part of CIDR space `172.31.0.0/16` will be accepted(`target-local`), by this VPC.

---

But packets coming from internet have destination IP as public IP(which is assigned to either NAT of public subnet or any instance in public subnet),   as per below diagram:

[image]
AWS console allows to configure NAT with public IP to private IP translation table. But NAT gw is within public subnet, behind IGW.

---

VPC is an autonomous system on Internet with its own gateway(IGW). AWS console does not allow assigning public IP to IGW.

IGW is entry point to VPC... But IGW is not assigned any public IP. How a packet from internet reach to my vpc, if IGW has not been assigned a public IP?

Answer (score 0):

maybe i don't understand your question... but, imagin, all your public IPs sitting on the IGW.. then, he knows to which internal ip it has to translate. the IGW has a NAT table. in general, it looks like "public IP -> internal IP". so, when a packet arrives on your IGW, it rewrites the destination of the IP header to your internal address. this is some sort of configuration you can't see anywhere in your aws console. The oposite, if your server answers to that request, the IGW translate the private address in the source portion of the IP Header

when you create an instance and choose to automatically assign an public ip address, the AWS orchestrator automatically configures the IGW to point that public IP to your Instance.

What if you have a "nonpublic" subnet and you want to reach the internet just from inside the VPC to the outside? then you need a NAT Gateway. The NAT gateway hides all private IPs with just ONE public IP. this means, all packets source address from your nonpublic subnets are translated to ONE public IP. this means, you can initiate a connection TO the internet, but nobody can initiate a connection to your servers. this is called NAT-Overload. with this techique NAT uses the tcp/udp ports as an translation identifier. like this: sourcePrivate-ipX:sourcePort32001 translated to sourcePublicIP:sourcePort32001... then, when the return packet comes, NAT-GW looks into the destination address and port and knows to which private IP it has to send the packet

**edit**... aaahhh now i understand... you are mixing up IGW and NAT-GW! you only need a NAT-GW in your public subnet if you have private subnets which want to connect to the internet. NAT-GW and Internet GW are 2 pairs of shoes where both of them performing Translations :-)

Comment: IGW has no translation table. No public IP is assigned to IGW unlike NAT. IGW is entry point for incoming packet.

Comment: i do not agree : An internet gateway serves two purposes: to provide a target in your VPC route tables for internet-routable traffic, and to perform network address translation (NAT) for instances that have been assigned public IPv4 addresses. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Comment: yes, its the entrypoint. and its the device which is responsible for translating packets... its the interface between virtual and physical stuff

Comment: My point is, AWS console allows NAT gw  to assign public IP, but AWS console does not allow IGW to assign public IP. You can verify this.

Comment: yes, nat-gw is a device which belongs to your vpc... you can add an elastic ip to it... now wonder on which device this elastic ip sits? on the IGW :-).... the igw is some kind of loadbalancer providing internet access to all vpcs.. this device is under control of aws and luckely, of course you can not configure it